# custom UINavigationBar appearence without spaces

Tags: iphone, custom-controls

I was wondering if it is possible to style a UINavigationBar using the appearance functions from iOS 5 like in the following image:

[image: UINavigationBar]

The Back Button is aligned to the left without any spaces. On the right side I want to have an other button or many buttons. Also no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your navigationbar to look like the image you've posted then use the customnavigation that means hide your original navigationbar at the launch of your project and create a view in xib with the 2 buttons and images and all customization as per your need and size that view of 44 height and place it on top of your viewcontroller so in that way your customizedview will work like your navigationbar and looks same as your above stated image.tell me if you need any example for that. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I see, so I can't "just" use the appearence API. Custom controls aren't that hard. I was just wondering if this would be possible.